# Getting all edges going out from a node in jgrapht

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht, jgraph

I am trying to randomly traverse through the graph in jgrapht (until I find some target node). To do it, I need to start at the sourceNode, randomly pick any coming out edge and follow it.

I know there there is a method `getAllEdges(sourceVertex, targetVertex)` that returns all the edges between two given nodes. But how can I get all edges while having only sourceNode, without the target one?

Comment: Can't see any direct API for doing that. What you can do is either 1. get all the vertices (perhaps using `vertexSet()` method) and then pass each vertex from this set as `targetVertex` for the method `getAllEdges()` and combine the results of all these calls. or 2.  get all edges using `edgeSet()` method. Then for each of these edges call `getEdgeSource(E e)` to get sourceVertext. Then compare it eith given vertex  to see if this edge starts from the given vertex. Collect these edges and you have your desired result.

Comment: It will probably work, but how efficient is this? I've got quite a big graph to analyze.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, as there is not out-of-the-box API, I'd suggest you to take a look at the source and then extend the class to create your own implementation of say getAllEdgesStartingFromVertex(V vertex). That also enables you optimize the method the way you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Graphs.predecessorListOf and Graphs.successorListOf apis directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the outgoing edges of a node(vertex) with `outgoingEdgesOf` method of a graph object.

```
Set<MyEdge> edges = myGraph.outgoingEdgesOf(sourceNode);
```

Also, you can use `incomingEdgesOf` for the incoming edges.

If you want to access all edges of a node then use

```
graph.edgesOf(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any object that implements the interface `Graph<V,E>` should have the method `edgesOf(V vertex)`, at least according to the [API](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/). Your `TransportGraph` should be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wondered, I did not find any direct way to achieve this, so I went with Balkrishna suggestion from comments. My implementation (Java 8 style) is:

```
   private List<WeightedEdge> getAllEdgesFromNode(TransportGraph graph, MyNode startNode) {
    return graph.unwrap().edgeSet().stream()
            .filter(weightedEdge -> graph.unwrap().getEdgeSource(weightedEdge).equals(startNode))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note: TransportGraph is a wrapper for jgrapht graph I have written myself. My method unwrap() returns SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph,

Answer (score -2):

I was trying to comment milez answer, but I mistakenly wrote it as an answer.
So, let's write the answer.
Milez proposed using JGrapht library, which I have used myself several times and works quite fine.
This library has a RandomWalkIterator class which I think meets the requirements.

Comment: Sorry, this was intended to be a comment to the answer by milez and it went into the wrong place. My mistake. milez proposed JGrapht library, which has a RandomWalkIterator class. In my opinion, it implements exactly the requested functionality.